# Which article should I use when referring to a program function's argument?

Tags: articles, definite-article, indefinite-article

Let's say I'm documenting a library function that (for example) accepts a number and returns the number squared. Should I write

> This function squares **the** given number.

or

> This function squares **a** given number?

At the time of writing the sentence, there is no particular number we'd be referring to. But at the time the function is executed, there is a concrete number that is being squared.

Comment: Your use of **given** might have some semantic interference from the phrase **a given**, as in "On a given day, I might be anywhere from Alaska to Nebraska".  Using the word **the** avoids this interference.

Comment: You should also go over to http://programmers.stackexchange.com and read the wealth of commentary there about why commenting on the obvious is a bad thing.  (E.g. `i = i + 1 //add one to i`)

Comment: The words "this function" are redundant, given that the comment is likely to be right next to the top of the function.

Comment: @Hellion In my case, the behavior of the function is nontrivial. I just chose this simple example so that the question isn't obscured by technical details.

Answer (score 3):

Either is acceptable, since what is in play is "whatever number is given", which is indefinite in the code but definite at run time.

But presumably your code gives a name to your 'given number'; why not employ that? That is,

> `function Sqr(Arg)  \\ this function returns the square of Arg` *mutatis mutandis* for whatever syntax your language employs.

---

ADDED:
As snailplane points out, it is important to avoid any possibility of ambiguity, following the Writer's Prime Rule: “Anything which *can* be misunderstood *will* be.” So it's probably a good general practise never to refer to any program entity by such a periphrasis or circumlocution as *given number*: refer to it by name.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comments, the best documentation is well-written code. However, I will assume that you are documenting a function that needs a little bit more explanation.

As a programmer, typically, I would describe the parameter by name, or at least by its type, and if it is by type, I would use "**a**" instead of "**the**" because "**a**" can be any value of that type, while "**the**" sounds like it is describing a specific value.

Example comment referencing the parameter type:

```
// Returns the square of an integer
function int square(int value)
```

Example comment referencing the parameter names:

```
// Returns width multiplied by height
function int area(int width, int height) {
```